# Selling a homemade product: dos and donts

Tags: united-states, business, creative-commons, branding, product-liability

if a person wants to sell a mixture of oils for hair growth or to thicken hair but the product they create is, well, a mixture of various oils (brands don’t necessarily matter, it’s whatever is available and is the purest form of the oil) so would those brands have to be credited? Or can the person just say coconut oil, olive oil etc.
and would the brands be able to have a claim in what is earned?

Comment: If you're not naming the brands, why would they have a claim to what is earned? You've already paid them for the oil.